# Populating for loop counts in new column

Tags: r, loops, apply, grepl

I'm trying to count the number of times each row value in df1's Column A appears in df2's Column B, then populate the corresponding counts in a new column in df1.

**df1**

```
ColumnA  
A_10   
A_11
A_12
A_13
A_14
```

**df2**

```
ColumnB
A_10, A_50
A_10, A_50
A_14, A_50
A_50, A_10
```

**Desired output**

```
ColumnA  New_Column
A_10      3
A_11      0
A_12      0
A_13      0
A_14      1
```

**My Code:**

```
df1$new_column <- 0

for (i in df1$ColumnA) {
   df$new_column[i] <- sum(grepl(i, df2$ColumnB), na.rm = TRUE)
  }
```

Been cracking my head the whole day, including looking at forum questions - What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the data in `df2` on comma, `count` each individual entry and join it with `df1`. We replace the `NA` values with 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  separate_rows(ColumnB, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  count(ColumnB) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c('ColumnB' = 'ColumnA')) %>%
  mutate(n = replace_na(n, 0))

#  ColumnB     n
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 A_10        3
#2 A_14        1
#3 A_11        0
#4 A_12        0
#5 A_13        0
```

and using `grepl` :

```
df1$New_Column <- sapply(df1$ColumnA, function(x) sum(grepl(x, df2$ColumnB)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! After reviewing, I realize my question needs to be revised to reflect the original problem I'm trying to solve. I have updated the example.

Comment: Can you check if the updated answer solves the problem?

Comment: Creative solution! I was hoping to utilize grepl or string matching, because in my real world example (which I can't share here), Column B would contain a very long string denoting different levels in an organizational hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, in that case we can use `grepl` as well. I have updated answer with that approach.

Comment: Just finished running a huuuge file with your code, took 12 hours, and it worked!! Thanks so much, you're the best!